# what is naming convention for laravel cache tags multi words?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, tags

i want to use best naming convention for cache tag key but i could not find it. i checked in official docs and other websites for example for cache tag but i could find only 1 word tags ,  should i use same casing as variable name or other format like `globalMenus` or should i use global:menus or global_menus. i am looking for best practices.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#cache-tags

```
Cache::tags(['globalmenus')->get('slider_media');
```

Comment: Don't think there's best practice for this, I think it's a preference thing. For example, we cache like `HostId-15-LangId-2-footernav` or `HostId-10-LangId-5-sliderItems-homepage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything would work really. But if you look at how Laravel does it you'll see:

```
cache:tag:calls:key
cache:63be6acad:standard_ref
app:horizon:measured_queues
app:horizon:completed_jobs
```

So I'd say use **underscores** for separating words and **colons** for separating groups

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9203fca96960ef9cd8860cb4ec99d1279353a8d/tests/Cache/CacheTaggedCacheTest.php#L236

Answer (score 0):

I would go with kebab case for cache tags as this is how Laravel uses Blade component tags in [rendering components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-components)